# Is α-keratin a fully functional protein?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, homework, protein-structure

Is α-keratin before it coils with another polypeptide, makes chains, and build intermediate filaments a fully functional protein?

I mean, is the single monomer of α-keratin a protein or does it have to become a dimer to become a protein?

Comment: This question appears to be answered in the [wikipedia article on α-keratin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-keratin) ...

Answer (score -1):

What we call as protein is the final quaternary structure. Whether it is translated from a single gene or from multiple genes (as in haemoglobin), *always the structure with all bonds and interactions taken into account*. Similarly here the alpha- Keratin forms Disulfide bonds to form a functional protein.